# composer git repository checkout as git-repo and not as a copy

Tags: git, composer-php, typo3

I've a composer based TYPO3 installation, which contains a private gitlab-repository. The private git-repository should be used as `dev-master` (as a real repository) so that I'm able to develope inside. But composer checks out only the master repository files, but without the `.git` folder.

Any clue what's wrong? In some other projects this works like expected.

My composer.json:

```json
{
    "name": "my-vendor/my-project",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Website",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "platform-check": false,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "typo3/class-alias-loader": true,
            "typo3/cms-composer-installers": true,
            "captainhook/plugin-composer": true
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" },
        { "type": "path", "url": "./packages/*" },
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "git@gitlab.com:myvendor/typo3-amp.git" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-about": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-backend": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-dashboard": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-filelist": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-fluid": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-frontend": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-install": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-opendocs": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-recordlist": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-recycler": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-scheduler": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^11.0",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^11.0",
        "helhum/typo3-console": "~7.0",
        "my-vendor/sitepackage": "@dev",
        "my-vendor/amp": "dev-master as 2.0.0",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-libxml": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-json": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.98",
        "saschaegerer/phpstan-typo3": "^0.13.3",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.0",
        "captainhook/captainhook": "^5.10",
        "captainhook/plugin-composer": "^5.3",
        "rector/rector": "0.11.53"
    },
    "extra": {
        "captainhook": {
            "force-install": true
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "php-cs-fixer": "vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix packages",
        "phpstan": "vendor/bin/phpstan analyse",
        "rector": "vendor/bin/rector process packages",
        "ci": [
            "@php-cs-fixer",
            "@phpstan",
            "@rector"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look in the [manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs):

> If you set the no-api key to true on a github repository it will clone the repository as it would with any other git repository instead of using the GitHub API. But unlike using the git driver directly, Composer will still attempt to use github's zip files.

The simple trick seems to be *not* to use the `vcs` driver but instead the `git` driver for the private repo...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

Add this to your `composer.json`

```json
"preferred-install": {
   "my-vendor/amp": "source"
}
```

then remove the package by using `rm typo3conf/ext/amp` and then do a `composer install`